# How do i connect my image in laravel+js framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

Heyy guys, i am currently learning Laravel but using JS as the frontend

its basic but i struggling with it :(

**The code**

```
            <div className='hexagonal'>
                <img src="../../public/img/Hexagonal1.webp" alt="Hexagon" />
            </div>
            <div className='firstpage'>
```

but when i check the frontend, the image is crashing and when i check the console its always 404 not Found.

my image is inside the public/img folder , and my code is inside resources/js/Pages/Homepage.jsx , the image is below so you guys can check the folder tree structure

[image: Folder Tree]

i appreciate any help, thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps change `../../public/img` to `../../../img` or if public is in the root `/public/img`

Comment: it is ../../../img loll , its 3 times, thank you so much Mr. Schultheiss, i'll make this as answer in a min, thank you